# pytest-html: Add comments in each testcase, so it appears in the link (show details) on the .html report?

Tags: pytest-html

Would like to add comments throughout my test cases as a progress indicator, and have them appear in the .html report when you click the 'show details' link.  These comments could be many and be some alpha-numeric string.

Prefer to use pytest with pytest-html:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def starting_shift():
    on_duty = True
    return on_duty


def test_rep1(starting_shift):
    print('')
    print("(test_rep1)  starting_shift=({})".format(starting_shift))
    assert starting_shift


def test_rep2(starting_shift):
    print('')
    if starting_shift:
        print("starting_shift=({}).  WILL change to 'False'.".format(starting_shift))
        starting_shift = False
    print("(test_rep2)  starting_shift=({})".format(starting_shift))
    assert starting_shift
```

Terminal output:

```
test_comments.py::test_rep1 
(test_rep1)  starting_shift=(True)
PASSED
test_comments.py::test_rep2 
starting_shift=(True).  WILL change to 'False'.
(test_rep2)  starting_shift=(False)
FAILED
```

[report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJqkn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer:  Don't use -v-s.  Output didn't go into report, when I used it.